# Loop through a checkbox list

Tags: asp.net, foreach, checkboxlist

I am building a checkbox lists:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxes" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And trying to get the value's of the selected items:

```
List<Guid> things = new List<Guid>();
foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxes.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
        things.Add(item.Value);
    }
}
```

I get the errror

> "The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Guid)'
>   has some invalid arguments "

Comment: If an item from the list is selected, you want to add this same item to the thing list. Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'thing' list is excepting a Guid value. You should convert item.value to a Guid value:

```
List<Guid> things = new List<Guid>();
foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxes.Items)
{
  if (item.Selected)
    things.Add(new Guid(item.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ListItem.Value` is of type `System.String`, and you're trying to add it to a `List<Guid>`.  You could try:

```
things.Add(Guid.Parse(item.Value));
```

That will work as long as the string value is parsable to a `Guid`.  If that's not clear, you'll want to be more careful and use `Guid.TryParse(item.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your List's Add method does accept GUID's (see the error message), but isn't accepting "item.value", then I'd guess item.value is not a GUID.

Try this:

```
...
things.Add(CTYPE(item.value, GUID))
...
```