# For loop on multiple check boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have checkboxes named CheckBox1,CheckBox3,CheckBox5,CheckBox7,CheckBox9,CheckBox11. I wants to iterate through these check boxes and wants to disable them. I have written like this

```
for (int i=1; i < 12; i++)
{              
    ((CheckBox)(i.ToString())).Enabled = false;
    i=i+2;
}
```

but this is not the proper way. please help

Comment: Alternatively, consider using a CheckBoxList. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260428/loop-through-a-checkbox-list

Comment: For some reason you cannot use CheckBoxList, as suggested above, which I think is appropriate, Consider obtaining reference to those checkbox using: `(this.FindControl("<construct your checkbox ID>") as CheckBox)`

Comment: Having that line `i=i+2` in the loop will cause your loop to go: i=1, i=4, i=7, i=10. Either put `for (int i=1; i < 12; i+2)` or change it in the loop to `i=i+1`

Comment: @Basic correct me if I'm wrong but will it not do: `i=i+2` at the end of the loop then `i++` when continuing the loop? So essentially `i=i+3`

Comment: also as mentioned below, my previous comment where I said `for (int i=1; i < 12; i+2)` I should have said `for (int i=1; i < 12; i+=2)`

Comment: @iabbott Sorry, you're absolutely right - I hadn't realised `i` was being incremented in the `for()` too as it's unusal to do both. I'll delete my comments to remove clutter. Apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `FindControl` like this if you have id of controls like Checkbox1,Checkbox3 etc.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i+=2)
{
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("Checkbox" + i);
  cb.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Instead of having i++ and then incrementing i by i = i+2, just have i+2 in the loop declaration

Comment: @NWard thanks I didn't see that part. but thanks for that good point. I have updated the post

Comment: `i += 2`, otherwise your updating same instance over and over (`i` won't increase)

Answer (score 0):

May this help you.

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
{
   if (c is CheckBox)
   {
      CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)c;
      myCheckBox.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

This will disable you all CheckBoxes you have.
Edit: Sorry didnt see the +2 at the `i`. My fault.

Comment: I thought of something similar but control names "1,3,5" suggest there are other checkboxes that need to stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Your code would like to set the enabled=false for checkboxes that have an odd number at the end of their id?  Then this will do that

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
{
   if (ctrl is CheckBox && ctrl.id.length > 9)
   {
      int chkboxNumber = int.Parse(ctrl.id.SubStr(9));
      if ( chkboxNumber % 2 == 1) // Check for odd numbers
      {
          (CheckBox)ctrl.Enabled = false; 
      }
   }
}
```